# Set Row Count of Grid Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very large dataset(can be up to 3 million items) that I am retrieving on demand based on the scroll position of a grid.  This means that I will never have all the items in one collection. But, I need the grid to be interactive and allow the user to scroll as if all the items were in memory.

So, I need a way to set the amount of rows (data items) so that the scroll bar will be the proper size for my database collection. I know the total number of items in the database, so I just need to set the total number of rows in the grid to match that number.

Is there a simple way to do this in WPF with a Datagrid or GridView?

Edit: The important thing is that the scroll bar is properly sized. That way the collection can be indexed based off of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama what exactly would you like me to change? I've read that and found that my questions adheres to those guidelines.

Comment: This seems like a strange (and painful) way to go about dynamically loading info into a grid.

Comment: @DangerZone I totally agree. I've tried other methods, but the records are retrieved over a network and their size is far too big to be stored in memory. So, loading on demand seems to be the best way to accomplish this with performance in mind.

Comment: @jprogrammer why not load chunks at a time, similar to a web search? (ie. "Next" or "Load more" buttons) Also 3 million records is far too much for an individual person to analyze anyway, can you not filter irrelevant data from the retrieval? These are just thoughts, not that they can necessarily apply to your situation.

Comment: @DangerZone My current method uses filtering, but sometimes that filtering process has to do a lot of work for things like wildcards. So I want to have the filtered request, but only return enough results to fill out the current view of the grid. Which is essentially loading a chunk at a time with the scroll bar serving as the "load more".

Comment: @DangerZone We have this implemented elsewhere in our source, but not used in C#. One of the main things I was told that was needed was being able to tell the datagrid its size so that the scroll bar would size properly. Everything else is implemented and functional.

Comment: Do you retrieve data from a SQL server?

Comment: @jprogrammer generally speaking when code is involved then you need a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; in addition you need to show what you have tried, research you've done, etc In other words "proof" of effort put in before asking the question

Answer (score 0):

Use event handlers for several button controls to make buttons: Next, Previous, First, Last. Parameterise the SQL called by these buttons with firstrow and lastrow inputs say 1 to 10. Each time Next is called, the SQL will spit out the next 10 rows. The rows on the grid per page will be equal to 10 in this case.